# Trouble trying to build app with Jenkins and latest android plugin 3.0.0-alpha8

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-databinding, gradlew

I have the Android studio 3.0 Canary preview and am able to build fine there. When I try to build on jenkins with gradlew I receive

> Could not find com.android.databinding:baseLibrary:3.0.0-alpha8.

I thought maybe the google() repo wasn't working but you'd think that would error out itself so I replaced

```
google()
```

with

```
maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
```

and I still get the same error. The only reference that I have in my build.gradle for databinding is

```
android {
   dataBinding.enabled = true
}
```

my gradle wrapper has a distribution url of

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-milestone-1-all.zip
```

does anyone have an Idea of what I'm doing wrong or let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same error here.

It's because you use Android Studio Canary Version.

Build Tools are include in package directly:

```
android-studio\gradle\m2repository\com\android\tools\build\gradle\3.0.0-alpha9
```

Comment: so how does one get Jenkins to run? I guess I'll try to manually force resolution of databinding to the latest public release

Comment: copy/paste folder com\android\tools\build\gradle\3.0.0-alpha9 on your server in [sdkpath]\extras\m2repository

Comment: I ended up using com.android.databinding latest from maven

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that version exists? Looking [here](https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.android.databinding.baseLibrary) it seems like it doesn't.

Keep in mind that `3.0.0-alpha8` (alpha9 as of now) is for `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle'`, and not necessarily other dependencies

Comment: then why does it work when I build it inside of Android Studio 3.0?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the local gradle like this:
[image: Settings → Build, Execution, Deployment → Gradle → Use local gradle distribution]